# Safari ignores my Jquery code for removing first word in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a UL LI list

```html
<ul class="tags no-animation clearfix" id="manufact">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <img>
            <span>Logo name</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <img>
            <span>Logo name</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to get rid of the word "Logo" as  is a duplicate.
My JS is

```js
$('#manufact li > a span').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    $(this).text(element[0].innerText.split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
});
```

In all browsers except Safari this (maybe not perfect JS) is OK, in Safari it COMPLETELY wipes out everything in SPAN and leaves it blank.

I want to have this result -

```html
<ul class="tags no-animation clearfix" id="manufact">
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <img>
            <span>name</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">
            <img>
            <span>name</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('#manufact li > a span').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    element.text(element.text().split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
});
```

Comment: Safari has some known bugs with the `innerText` function, jQuery knows it, so it's safer to keep using `text()` function in this case

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this more simply you can provide a function to `text()` which replaces only the word `Logo` at the start of the text value in each element. I haven't tested it, but this should work fine in Safari.

```js
$('#manufact li > a span').text((i, t) => t.replace(/^Logo\s?/i, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tags no-animation clearfix" id="manufact">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img>
      <span>Logo name</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">
      <img>
      <span>Logo name</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you *always* want to remove the first word in the `span`, no matter what that word is, then you can use your original logic with this pattern too:

```
$('#manufact li > a span').text((i, t) => t.split(' ').splice(1).join(' '));
```

Comment: And IT WORKS! Thanks!

Comment: And yes, different words in span.